# Uncaught ReferenceError: showNewsMenu is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is my widget. The problem is with the `click` function. It throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: showNewsMenu is not defined`.

The same thing occurs when I put this line into my `razorView`. I really don't have idea what can be wrong. Why is `showNewsMenu` not defined?

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("someNamespace.CmsMenu",
        {
            options:{
                menuContainer:'.cmsLeftPanel'
            },
            _create: function (){
            },
            showNewsMenu: function (){
                var button = document.createElement("input");
                button.type = "button";
                button.value = "Dodaj newsa";
                $(this.options.menuContainer).append(button);
           }
    });

    $('#NEWSY').click(showNewsMenu);  
  }
)
```

Comment: it is due to scope.  You are trying to reference a function that was created in an object being passed to `$.widget()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script was almost correct. Problem were in my cshtml (razorView) file.

I made initialization

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {       
        $('.cmsLeftPanel').CmsMenu();    
    });    

</script>
```

but i forgot to create this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function showNewsMenu() {
            $('.cmsLeftPanel').CmsMenu('showNewsMenu');
     }
</script>
```

No i can use it in html like onclick="showNewsMenu()"
and also like

```
$('#NEWSY').click(showNewsMenu);
```

in my cshmtl file.